# spring aop error 0 : unbound

Tags: spring, spring-aop

below mentioned is my aspect

```
@Aspect
public class TestAspect {

    @Around("execution (* com.test..*(..))")
    public void simonAspect(Joinpoint joinpoint) {
        System.out.println(" --- Interceptor --- ");

    }

}
```

and .xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    ... /schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="com.test.aspect.TestAspect" />


</beans>
```

on deployment i am receiving exception Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut

i am trying to intercept all methods of my controller classes defined in com.test package.

when i annotate class with @component the error does not come but interceptor is also not called.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Around("execution (* com.test..*(..))")
```

should be

```
@Around("execution (* com.test.*(..))")
```

or you can use whitin like this

```
@Around("within (* com.test.*)")
```

Comment: on changing this i am geeting error Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: com.test [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]

Answer (score 0):

An `Around` aspect expects you to return an `Object`

So, your aspect method should change to

```
@Around("execution (* com.test..*(..))")
public Object simonAspect(Joinpoint joinpoint) {
    System.out.println(" --- Interceptor --- ");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is i was using Joinpoint instead of JoinPoint. should be from import of org.aspectj.lang.* package.